# Handling iframe click in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I have an `iframe` embedded in html that loads a Google ad. The issue is when the ad is clicked on, the website it links to loads in the tiny iframe rather than opening a new `WebView` to display it properly. I've been searching on StackExchange quite a bit and found several similar problems, but none of the solutions worked for me. I've tried:

- using returning `false` from `shouldInterceptUrlLoading` (never even gets called)
- `shouldInterceptRequest` (never called)
- `onPageFinished` (called when original page loads, nothing on `iframe` click)
- and `onLoadResource`.

This last method has gotten me the closest, but trying to load the url results in infinitely stacking new, empty `WebView` fragments rather than loading the page as I expected.

Can anyone explain to me the proper way, from within a `WebView`, to detect an `iframe` click, capture the webpage the ad is trying load, and manually open it in a new `WebView`?